# get current git branch inside a java test

Tags: java, git

I need to get name of the current Git branch inside a Java test. Probably I can parse `git status` results. Is any other approach or a ready code snippet is available?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Works fine for me.

```
public static String getCurrentGitBranch() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD" );
    process.waitFor();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader( process.getInputStream() ) );

    return reader.readLine();
}
```

Comment: `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` would probably be better in this case

Comment: Yeah, that should be better. Thanks!

Comment: This may be a common sense comment, but don't forget to add "Git" to your system path. For Windows machine, you will have to find it somewhere inside the `C:\Users\[YOUR_USER_NAME]\AppData\Local` folder.

Comment: FWIW, the branch info is in the `.git/HEAD` file.